# ¿como finalizar una condición cuando se cumple?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

he realizado un ciclo para los usuarios que tiene diferente tipo de Jornadas laborales, ya que unos tiene Jornada 1 Jornada 2 hasta la jornada 8 con diferentes días laborales y de descanso.

Lo que estoy haciendo es que al momento de ingresar el numero de usuario me indique que tipo de Jornada tiene inicio y fin de la jornada y si esa jornada esta activa o inactiva para poder utilizar esta información en un calendario.

En el calendario puedo mostrar la jornada que tiene actualmente Activa pintando los días laborales y de descanso de diferente color ahora lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que quiero pintar también la jornada que tiene inactiva para la momento de ir yo al calendario pueda ver yo sus días laborales y de descanso con los diferentes tipos de Jornadas que tiene el Usuario.

De momento muestro los días laborales y de descanso de la Jornada Activa, he colocado un if (e.day.date == fechaFinJornada) indicando que si mi fin de la jornada es igual al día del evento se detenga y no me muestre más dias pintados de este color y que continué con lo que sigue en este caso a pintar la los dias de acuerdo a la Jornada siguiente que es la que tiene activa.

```
private void calFecha_DayRender(object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)  //Colores en Calendario
        {
            bool final = true;
            if (ddloperadores.SelectedValue != "Todos")
            {                
                DataTable asistencia = OperadoresBL.OperadoresForaneosAsistencia((int)WAPS.Globals.ConvertTo(txtNumOperador.Text, 0)).Tables[0];    //Datos de Store 

                    if (asistencia.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow iRow in asistencia.Rows)
                        {
                        string Tipo = iRow["TipoJornada"].ToString();
                        DateTime FechaJornada = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["Jornada_Ini"]);
                        string Cambio = iRow["cambio"].ToString();
                        string Estatus = iRow["Estatus"].ToString();
                        DateTime FechaFinJornada = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["Jornada_Fin"]);

                        if (Cambio == "1") //1.-Fue modificado de Jornada
                        {
                            datFechaInicio.Enabled = true;
                        }
                        if ((Tipo == "1") && (Estatus == "2") )//Tipos de Jornadas
                        {                            
                            if (FechaJornada <= e.Day.Date) 
                            {                                
                                    lblJornada.Text = "8x2";
                                    int rem = (e.Day.Date - FechaJornada).Days % 10; //Total de días                                       
                                        if (rem >= 0 && rem <= 7) //Días Laborales  
                                        {
                                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                                            if (e.Day.Date.Date == FechaFinJornada)
                                            {
                                                break;
                                            }

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                                            if (e.Day.Date.Date == FechaFinJornada)
                                            {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                return;
                                            }
                                        }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                            }
                        }
                        if ((Tipo == "2") && (Estatus == "1"))
                        {
                            lblJornada.Text = "12x3";
                            if (FechaJornada <= e.Day.Date)
                            {                             
                                    int rem = (e.Day.Date - FechaJornada).Days % 15;//Total de días
                                    if (rem >= 0 && rem <= 11) //Días Laborales        
                                    {
                                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;                                       
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;                                       
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Lo que logro con esto es mostrar las dos jornadas pero no se detiene las dos se siguen pintando en el calendario.[image: Calendario]

Muestro el calendario que estoy pintando, color naranja son descansos los blanco Laborales Jornada 1 .-  2 descansos 8 laborales Jornada 2.- 3 Descansos 12 laborales.

espero me puedan dar algún comentario.

gracias

Comment: El código está muy dificil de leer. Lineas largas, muchas lineas, mucha indentación. Mi recomendación es que dividas el problema en funciones discretas.

Comment: Me da la impresión de que `calFecha_DayRender` se ejecuta por cada día. Si es así, deberías tener un contador como estado por fuera de la función para saber si tienes que pintar o no.

Comment: gracias David, modifique en lugar de return coloque un continue si me lo detiene ahora la jornada anterior pero no me colorea los días anteriores solo el día en que termina la jornada y continua con la nueva jornada pintando los días sin problemas. Alguna otra sugerencia que me puedas dar. Gracias